# struck me as funny

Tags: phrase-meaning

From *[The Godfather](https://books.google.com/books?id=bDQD1YUcCXkC&pg=PA14)*:

> Hagen said quietly, "Sollozo wasn't worried about Luca, which struck me **as funny**. He's too smart not to worry about a guy like Luca. I think he maybe got him out of the picture, one way or another."

Why do we use the verb ***strike*** along with ***as funny***? I think ***to strike*** has a similar meaning to ***to hit***, so I can't get what Hagen was trying to say by this.

Comment: Check this out: **[strike](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/strike#strike_40)** in Macmillan Dictionary. Sense 6: "if a thought or idea strikes you, it enters your mind suddenly or unexpectedly".

Comment: I'd recommend looking not just at Sense 6, but at Senses 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, and 15 as well. Or, try [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/strike), starting around Sense 12, and reading all the way down to Sense 35. Then, you'll see how much _"I think to strike has a similar meaning to to hit"_ doesn't even come close to telling the whole story, and why I'd recommend checking a dictionary before posting a question here. [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/strike) lists these senses: _hit, remove, discover, feel/think, agree, pose, mint_.

Answer (score 4):

Check one of the definitions under [***strike***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/strike) sense 10:

> 10) to affect as if by contact, a blow, etc. (; specif.,)
>
> a. to come into the mind of; occur to   ⇒ "an idea struck me"
>   b. to be attractive to or impress (someone's fancy, sense of humor, etc.)
>   c. to seem to   ⇒ "an idea that strikes me as silly"
>   d. to cause to become suddenly   ⇒ "to be struck dumb"
>   e. to influence, inspire, or overcome suddenly with strong feeling   ⇒ "to be struck with amazement"
>   f. to cause (a feeling, emotion, etc.) to come suddenly; arouse   ⇒ "to strike terror to the heart"

It is more of a figurative strike and not a physical one.

In your example, I think sense 10c is the closest.

Answer (score 4):

The verb "strike" is used in different senses. You can also use it when something gives someone a particular feeling, impression, or opinion, as in the following examples:

> She struck me as a silly girl.
>
> How did London strike you?
>
> He struck me as a religious man.
>
> Your statement strikes him as funny/odd.

The OP's sentence in question conveys the meaning mentioned in these examples.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with user3169 and Khan.

Here is a way to visualize the metaphor:

Many people tilt their heads to get a different view of thing(s) they are looking at.  This literally gives them a different perspective.

Some people tilt their heads (and/or look off into space) when they are thinking about something.  This figuratively gives them a different perspective.

Some people tilt their heads when a new idea occurs to them, especially if the new idea is surprising.

If you slap someone on the side of their head, you will make their head tilt.  Also, you will (probably) change what they are thinking about.  (Their new thought might be "Ow!  That hurt!" or "Where did that come from?")

Thus, both being figuratively struck by a new idea, and literally being struck in the head can have the same effects -- they can both make a person's head tilt, and they both change a person's thoughts.